XCode lldb Error error: module 'GTMSessionFetcherCore' not found
suddenly lldb po command stopped working in XCode.
When I'm trying to use it, it gives the following error:
error: couldn't IRGen expression: Clang importer error
error: /Users/User/Git/Project/Pods/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn/Sources/Public/GoogleSignIn/GIDGoogleUser.h:27:9: error: module 'GTMSessionFetcherCore' not found
@import GTMSessionFetcherCore;

In the file mentioned in the error there is the following code:
#ifdef SWIFT_PACKAGE
@import GTMSessionFetcherCore;    <------ line 27
#else
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.h>
#endif

I have a GTMSessionFetcherCore in the project but as a pod.
So I don't understand why this line is considered to be true: #ifdef SWIFT_PACKAGE. Didn't change anything in the project.
Tried to clean the cache, remove DerivedData, and relaunch XCode, but nothing helped.
XCode Version 15.2
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Same problem on my side.

https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS/issues/396

Just use the latest commit from master branch in case you are using GoogleSignIn framework, here is an detailed info:
https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS/issues/396
